# Does applying a stash involve three way merge, or just patching a stash to the current working tree?

Tags: git

Manpage of `git stash` says

> ```
> pop [--index] [-q|--quiet] [<stash>]
> ```
>
> Remove a single stashed state from the stash list and apply it on top
>   of the current working tree state, i.e., do the inverse operation of 
>   git stash push . The working directory must match the index.
>
> Applying the state can fail with **conflicts**; in this case, it is not
>   removed from the stash list. You need to resolve the conflicts by hand
>   and call  git stash drop  manually afterwards.

Does "Applying the state" involve three way merge, or just patching a stash to the current working tree?

What kind of "conflicts" is it? I only know the conflict from three way merge.

Thanks.

Comment: 3way merge, I'd say. Otherwise stashing, switching branch and then applying it would not lead to the desired outcome (apply the changes on the new branch).

Comment: what are the three ways in the merging by git stash pop?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Applying the state" is indeed a three-way merge.

You noted (from the documentation) in your question [How is a stash entry a child commit of HEAD commit and index's commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54318663/1256452) that:

> The ancestry graph looks like this:
>
> ```
>        .----W
>       /    /
> -----H----I
> ```
>
> where `H` is the `HEAD` commit, `I` is a commit that records the state of the index, and `W` is a commit that records the state of the working tree.

I'm going to break `git stash pop` into its two component parts, which are `git stash apply` followed by `git stash drop`.  If the apply step succeeds, `pop` executes the `drop` step as well.  If not—if it stops with a conflict, for instance—`pop` skips the `drop`.  The `git stash` code is currently [literally a shell script](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/git-stash.sh)—I'd say "just" a shell script, but it is a pretty big and complex one weighing in at well over 700 lines—and [the `pop` code](https://github.com/git/git/blob/16a465bc018d09e9d7bbbdc5f40a7fb99c21f8ef/git-stash.sh#L658-L669) literally reads this way:

```
pop_stash() {
    assert_stash_ref "$@"

    if apply_stash "$@"
    then
        drop_stash "$@"
    else
        status=$?
        say "$(gettext "The stash entry is kept in case you need it again.")"
        exit $status
    fi
}
```

which as you can see says *apply, and if that works, drop; if it doesn't work, print an informative line and quit with the same status code that apply would have quit with.*

#### Applying the index (`I`) commit

Because each stash has at least two commits—the `I` index-state and the `W` work-tree-state—the *apply* step can apply *both* of them, or not.  At the time you run `git stash apply` or `git stash pop`, *you* choose whether to apply both, or just the `W` state.  If you choose to apply both, the `I` state is applied with what amounts to:

```
git diff <hash-of-H> <hash-of-I> | git apply --cached
```

(though the [actual line of code](https://github.com/git/git/blob/16a465bc018d09e9d7bbbdc5f40a7fb99c21f8ef/git-stash.sh#L599) is slightly different, to allow for binary files in the index, and is preceded and followed by some rather tricky magic to handle various corner and hard cases).

Because this is just `diff | patch` it is not a true three-way merge.  For details on what this implies, see [What is the difference between git cherry-pick and git format-patch | git am?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52119937/1256452) (both [Mark Adelsberger's accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52120407/1256452) and [my own](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52121093/1256452)).  In any case, the patch may fail.  If it does fail, you have the option of using `git stash branch` instead of `git stash apply --index`, which is guaranteed to work.

#### Applying the work-tree (`W`) commit

In any case, assuming you've either chosen to ignore the `I` commit, or have successfully applied it and Git has squirreled the result away for later in the apply process, Git now moves on to the three-way merge you were asking about.

This part is pretty tricky.  The heart of it, though, is [this line](https://github.com/git/git/blob/16a465bc018d09e9d7bbbdc5f40a7fb99c21f8ef/git-stash.sh#L626):

```
if git merge-recursive $b_tree -- $c_tree $w_tree
```

which runs a three-way merge with the merge base being commit `H`, the `--ours` commit being whatever was in the index when you started the merge, and `--theirs` commit being the contents of the `W` commit.

**Note: `git merge-recursive` tries to accommodate whatever is in the work-tree when you start the merge, even if it does not match the index contents that act as the `ours` tree.  This is not always successful, which is why it's often a bad idea to `git stash pop` into a dirty work-tree.**

If there are merge conflicts, these three trees—`$b_tree` from the `H` commit, `$c_tree` from [a tree that `git stash` made from your index before running `git merge-recursive`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/16a465bc018d09e9d7bbbdc5f40a7fb99c21f8ef/git-stash.sh#L591-L593), and `$w_tree` from commit `W`—are the three sources for files that go into the index in the merge-conflict staging slots, as I described in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46331568/1256452) to [Git Stash Pop - Resolve Conflicts with mergetool](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46330531/1256452).

**Note that if you do use `git mergetool` to merge them, this generally throws away any unstaged changes you had in your work-tree when you started the merge.  This, too, is a reason it is generally unwise to start a `git stash pop` or `git stash apply` with a dirty work-tree.**  If your work-tree matches your index when you start `git stash pop`, you will be in much better shape if a merge conflict occurs.

(**Edit, Jun 2022:** `git stash` is now C code, so that it's much harder to see what it does.  It now uses `git merge-ort` instead of `git merge-recursive` internally.  But the essentials are the same, including the problems that come up here.  I generally recommend *avoiding* `git stash` as much as you can, as it's really easy to have things go wrong.  Regular commits are much more user-friendly, if anything in Git can be called "user friendly" without a lot of loud sarcastic laughter.)

Comment: Thanks. What is the difference between patching and three way merge?

Comment: "In any case, the patch may fail. If it does fail, you have the option of using git stash branch instead of git stash apply --index, which is guaranteed to work". Why does `git stash branch` always succeed, while `git stash apply --index` might not?

Comment: What `git stash branch` does is to first check out the parent of the stash—commit `H` in the diagram—and create a new branch name pointing to that commit. Then it applies the index and work-tree changes as usual, and since they were relative to `H` and are being applied *to* `H`, applying the index and work-tree changes always succeeds.

Comment: Quick question: you specifically mention that `git stash pop` is not recommended in a dirty work-tree (in both of the bold paragraphs). But wouldn't the same happen with `git stash apply`? If they behave the same, it could be interpreted in a misleading way in that `git stash pop` might not be advised and thus maybe `git stash apply` would be a legit alternative.

Comment: @Michael: I dis-recommend (recommend against) `git stash` entirely, actually, so you're asking the wrong person. However, `git stash apply` means one thing, and `git stash pop` means *first, `git stash apply`, then do another git stash thing, namely `git stash drop`* and if the apply step has gone wrong invisibly, the `drop` step makes it significantly worse. It's bad enough when apply goes wrong. But overall I advise people to avoid `git stash` entirely; if you must use it, try to avoid `git stash pop` in particular.

Comment: All that said, I'll update this to mention both apply and pop, because you're right!